# List of open QtiPlot windows

Tags: python, plugins, scripting, plot, pyqt

I'm writing a plugin for QtiPlot using Python. Within the GUI of this plugin I'd like to display a dropdown that holds a list of all open windows of one sort of window (plots, tables, notes, etc.). On click on, for example, a item of a dropdown holding tables, I'd like to load this table to work with it. Are there any suggestions how to solve this problem?

The only thing I found is paragraph 7.2.6 of the [QtiPlot-Manual](http://depiq.cucei.udg.mx/Man/qtiplot/qtiplot-manual-en.pdf).

**EDIT**:
I'm now a step ahead. I'm now able to fetch a list of the subwindow names. But now I have a problem displaying the gui within the gtiplot scripting-window using the following code.

```
# Import system libraries.
import os,sys

# Import Qt modules.
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__();
        self.initUI();

    def initUI(self):
        # Set the window label.
        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel("", self);

        # Fetch the QMdiArea object ...
        ws = workspace();

        # ... and fetch all subwindows.
        subs = ws.subWindowList();

        # Initialize the combobox ...
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self);

        # ... and add the items.
        for sub in subs:
            combo.addItem(sub.objectName());

        combo.move(50, 50);
        self.lbl.move(50, 150);

        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated);    

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200);
        self.setWindowTitle('Subwindow DropDown');
        self.show();

    def onActivated(self, text):
        self.lbl.setText(text);
        self.lbl.adjustSize();

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv);
    widget = Widget();
    sys.exit(app.exec_());

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__();
        self.initUI();

    def initUI(self):
        # Set the window label.
        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel("", self);

        # Fetch the QMdiArea object ...
        ws = workspace();

        # ... and fetch all subwindows.
        subs = ws.subWindowList();

        # Initialize the combobox ...
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self);

        # ... and add the items.
        for sub in subs:
            combo.addItem(sub.objectName());

        combo.move(50, 50);
        self.lbl.move(50, 150);

        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated);    

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200);
        self.setWindowTitle('Subwindow DropDown');
        self.show();

    def onActivated(self, text):
        self.lbl.setText(text);
        self.lbl.adjustSize();

widget = Widget();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Translate to English please